# Python JSCON парсинг данных

Tags: python, json

```
s = json.dumps(response.json())
data = json.loads(s)

for xdata in data['data']:
      current_temperature = data.get('app_temp')
      current_pressure = data.get('city_name')
```

сам JSON

```
{'count': 1, 'data': [{'app_temp': 18.8, 'aqi': 25, 'city_name': 'Munich', 'clouds': 81, 'country_code': 'DE', 'datetime': '2022-10-26:14', 'dewpt': 14.9, 'dhi': 71.28, 'dni': 641.48, 'elev_angle': 16.97, 'ghi': 251.39, 'gust': 11.661642, 'h_angle': 45, 'lat': 48.13743, 'lon': 11.57549, 'ob_time': '2022-10-26 14:02', 'pod': 'd', 'precip': 0, 'pres': 960.3781, 'rh': 75, 'slp': 1021.69904, 'snow': 0, 'solar_rad': 153.2, 'sources': ['analysis', 'D1024'], 'state_code': '02', 'station': 'D1024', 'sunrise': '05:50', 'sunset': '16:05', 'temp': 18.9, 'timezone': 'Europe/Berlin', 'ts': 1666792937, 'uv': 0.9160536, 'vis': 16, 
'weather': {'description': 'Broken clouds', 'code': 803, 'icon': 'c03d'}, 'wind_cdir': 'WSW', 'wind_cdir_full': 'west-southwest', 'wind_dir': 252, 'wind_spd': 3.032793}]}
```

На вывод получаешь следующие данные:
`Temperature (in kelvin unit) = None`

Comment: 1. Это не json. В json кавычки двойные (если смотреть исходник, а не вариант после правок Sergey K). 2. В приведенном коде нет ничего что выводило бы текст "Temperature (in kelvin unit) =" поэтому невозможно сказать почему он выводит None, ибо не известно, а использует ли он вообще показанные в коде переменные

Comment: Но вообще у вас переменная xdata содержит блок "data" из json. Но вот app_temp вы при этом упорно ищете в data, а не в xdata ...

Comment: @Mike второй комментарий помог.. спасибо

Comment: data = response.json()